# Can't access getters in the store for Vue when in a template

Tags: javascript, data-binding, store, vue.js, vuex

I have a component with the following rendering ([computed props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties)). It works and shows the text as supposed to for *blopp* but nothing for *blipp*. In the final version, I want it to produce a list of strings brought from the state of the store and serve as *blipp*.

```
export default {
  computed:{
    blopp: function(){ return "ghjk,l"; },
    blipp: function(){ return this.$store.getters.getBlipp(); }
  }
}
```

It's rendered based on the following [template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Arguments).

```
<template>
  <div>
    ...
    <div v-bind:blopp="blopp">{{blopp}}</div>
    <div v-bind:blipp="blipp">{{blipp}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The [implementation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/structure.html) of the [store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getting-started.html) looks like this bringing the [getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html) to the open forum.

```
...
const state = { blipp: [], ... };
const getters = {
  getBlipp: function() { return state.Blipp; }, ...
}
export default new Vuex.Store({ state, mutations, actions, getters });
```

The second component gets no value in it at all and I'm not sure where to look for the cause.

I probably set it up incorrectly but it's a lot of moving parts and a bit hard to diagnose for the ignorant me. When I try to run the following in the console,

> temp.$store.getters

I get an object which lists the getters like this.

```
...
blipp:(...)
get blipp: function()
__proto__: Onject
```

Not certain what to do with that info... It appears to be a function but when I try to invoke it, it says it's undefinied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**getters** function in a similar manner to **states**. Therefore to resolve them you call a parameter not a method, i.e.

```
blipp: function() { return this.$store.getters.getBlipp }
```

In this case you probably want to rename `getBlipp` to simply `blipp`

I put together a JSFiddle which shows the various ways you can interact with vuex's store, hope it helps:

**[Example Vuex JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thebigsurf/sewvqspq/)**

Comment: Oh, dude... I got it right from the start **but** spelled the name of the property wrongly (forgot the plural form). So your answer both confirmed that I do get the stuff **and** proved that I'm a lazy ass developer who's depending on the power of intellisense, hehe. Stupid JavaScript with it stupid flexibility making me feel stupid for not spelling correctly, hahahaha. +1 for the effort on the fiddle. It's going to help in so many other ways. Really appreciated.